# Stop OnClientClick="aspnetForm.target ='_blank';" from firing from other control clicks?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have a page that has a linkbutton that opens a report. On this linkbutton if have OnClientClick="aspnetForm.target ='_blank';"  so the report opens in a new window/tab. This works as expected. I also have a regular button.

If the linkbutton is clicked first the second button also opens a new window when clicked. How do I stop this from happening?

I don't really know how to phrase the question properly so feel free to edit the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code for clientClick on LinkButton modifies the whole form target. You can probably just add

```
OnClientClick="aspnetForm.target ='_self';"
```

to the second (regular) button. This will again reassign form target - this time to 'self'.

Comment: That did it!! Thanks!! I should have thought of that myself.

Comment: Hey! Great answer. It helped me. But with a little variation that can be useful.
I am using DevExpress and doing some other processings in background.
So I used this: `function redirectBlank() {
    aspnetForm.target = '_blank';
    setTimeout(function () {
        redirectSelf();
    }, 500);
}

function redirectSelf() {
    aspnetForm.target = '_self';
}`
And in my button the `OnClientClick` calls the first function. Hope this help someone too.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you're reassigning the value of `aspnetForm.target` when you click the first button. Instead of this approach, why not use `window.open` instead?

```
OnClientClick="void(window.open('http://www.google.com')); return false;"
```

Comment: I have to use response.redirect. I have to do some calculations in my code behind and pass those new parameters to the report.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution using this approach in my view is reseting the specific form's target when clicking any of the other buttons included in this form.

`window.document.forms[0].target = '';`

If you don't like this approach, you can use setTimeout() to trigger this same line of code few moments after the new tab was opened.

Answer (score -1):

can you please try to render an HTML anchor(instead of asp:linkbutton) with href set to appropriate url and set the target attribute to _blank

```
<a href="urlOfThePage" target="_blank" >Click me</a>
```

Comment: I am using the linkbutton because I have to build the url from my code behind. I have to manipulate the parameters. I would use this if I didn't have change the parameters.